# Bluetooth audio connection confirmation with Tasker

Tags: bluetooth, tasker

Just bought Tasker, my goal is that when I get into my car I have a Jabra Freeway, it has a motion sensor and turns on when it detects motion. But my VZW Galaxy Nexus won't always connect. I get tired of checking, how do I go about creating a task or profile that would allow me to hear a notification sound to act as a confirmation that the phone connected. I'd like to get in, and hear for example a text tone on the Bluetooth to let me know it's connected. I need a step by step walkthrough. I haven't found one online?

Comment: I just found a related question which might be worth a look as well: [Can Tasker/Locale tell me what BT device is connected?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4533/16575). As *Tasker* and *Locale* share the same plugin interface, the answer from *Locale Support* is valid here as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the condition *State→Bluetooth Connected*:

> The device is connected to another device via Bluetooth. If either of Name or Address are specified, they must match a connected device.
>
> Connections to non-paired devices (e.g. while pairing is taking place) are ignored.
>
> Warning: Tasker can't directly detect when a BT device is connected, only when a connection or disconnection is made.

As for the task, take a look at *Music Play*:

> Play a sound file from the SD card.
>
> File is the path to the file on the SD card e.g. Music/wow.mp3

Alternatively: *Notify Sound*:

> Show a notification on the top bar and play a sound.
>
> The specified Title will appear on the bar initially. Notifications with a particular (non-empty) title replace existing ones with that title.
>
> When the notification area is pulled down, the specified Text will be visible.

Or *Notify Vibrate*, *Play Ringtone*, *Say* (Synthesize the given Text into speech)...

Trying a raw thing (I didn't test this):

- **Condition:** State→Bluetooth Connected (specify the parameters)
- **Task:** Say "You are connected now."

For more information, you might want to take a look at the [User Manual](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/). Also check the [Tasker Homepage](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) itself for more [Guides](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/guides.html), [FAQ](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/faq.html), How-Tos, etc. Moreover, the [Wiki](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/wiki) contains a lot of ready profiles, step-throughs, and more.

Comment: I'm still new, and can't upvote you yet with my reputation. But I really appreciate your help and you helped me figure it out. I can now also get my phone to tell me to buckle up or whatever I want which adds a cool factor! You're awesome. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome! If that solves your issue, you can hit the checkmark next to the answer to "accept" it. This shows to others: This is a workable solution :)

Comment: Yup, I choose the check mark to choose this as a solution... it took me a few minutes to figure it out, but I got it.